# my app not works error comes on intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i am new in this field 
sorry for my bad english
i want to make an app that perform to open second layout and in 2nd layout i want to open first layout
but an error come on my intent kindly guide me

```
 package com.example.ahmed.calling;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;   
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            setContentView(R.layout.my_layout2);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),second.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

my second class is

```
public class second extends MainActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout2);

    Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

error come on clicking the button it appers on first activity 
on line 25 i-e startactivity(intent) kindly guide me

my logcat error

```
10-15 00:32:14.968  26752-26752/? E/ConnectionService﹕ Failed to connect to GoogleApiClient: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}


10-15 00:32:16.296  26939-26939/com.example.ahmed.calling E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.ahmed.calling/com.example.ahmed.calling.second}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3389)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3350)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:748)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3562)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3528)
        at com.example.ahmed.calling.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4106)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17052)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
```

manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ahmed.calling" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest please

Comment: Also, you should post the error messages, exceptions and stacktrace from the logcat. This will help identify the problem.

Comment: `an error come on my intent`. ok. but don't you think it could help to be more specific regarding the error?

Comment: @DavidWasser and njzk2 now i have submitted my manifest  and logcat kindly help 
and thanks for the reply

Comment: Reading the logcat: `ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.ahmed.calling/com.example.ahmed.calling.second}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml` Then,, on AndroidManifest, no `calling.second`... go that direction, check ["activity declaration android"](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT IS WORKING NOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spotted three logical errors/issues in your codes, however for being certain outputs of logcat are needed.

- In your `MainActivity` class you don't need to change view hierarchy in that `onClick` callback. i.e. Remove `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout2);` in that method.
- You shouldn't use `getApplicationContext()` inside an Activity to start another Activity. You should use the reference to current Activity instead.

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  ```
- Also, there's no need to `finish` your Activities while you're starting another ones. They will be handled by the Android itself.

**UPDATE #1:**

Your logcat says:

> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.ahmed.calling/com.example.ahmed.calling.second}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

This means that you should first declare your activities in the AndroidManifest.xml, then you can start them.

**UPDATE #2:**

Your final manifest file should look like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE -->
    <activity android:name=".second"/>
</application>
```

Comment: These should all be comments. This doesn't answer the question or solve OP's problem.

Comment: @abforce i have does all these thing but same error occur 
now i have submitted my logcat kindly guide me further thanks

Comment: @EbadAhmed Okay, logcat says that you have not declared your activity in the manifest file. Just declare them in the AndroidManifest.xml, that's it.

Comment: @EbadAhmed Just add another `<activity>` tag for your `second` activity.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT IS WORKING NOW

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, your second Activity is not declared in the manifest. You need to add:

```
<activity android:name=".second"/>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT IS WORKING NOW